# Visual Studio 2017 Publishing no IIS,FTP option

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm having trouble with my visual studio 2017. I have a project that I need to deploy but there is no ISS,FTP option like sample image below.

[image]

all I have is this setup

[image]

Then I try to publish using that setup but all .vb file is included and it seems that it is not pre complied. Any help would be very much appreciated. I tried looking up over the web for any solution but didn't get any with the same scenario as mine.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What is in the previous window if you press the "< Prev" button?

Comment: It will show the previous tab like settings/connection/profile.